# How to separately click multiples a html tags with same classes and add style(s) to another div that has multiple classes Jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hyperlink

I created a section that has three links which when you click on one of them it displays some content. When you click each of the links individually it displays a specific content (content 1, content 2 and content 3).

You can seen from the screenshot there are two identical sections (Section 1 and Section 2).

My problem is when I am in either of the two sections, when I click on one of the links, the content that is being displayed is being displayed in both of the two sections at the same time. I want to have it when you are in a specific section and click on a link, it only shows that content in that specifici section, not both and displaying at the same time.

Any help in JQuery I would truly be grateful! I am also open to vanilla JavaScript solution as well.

My JQuery is not the greatest so what I currently have if there is a better way of coding it I am definitely open to it with the resolved answer.

Here is the Codepin for it:

```
<a href="https://codepen.io/dan-zins/pen/mdammed">codepen</a>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I searched within this site and other various sites but have not found a solution to resolve my specific issue. I tried data-id, $(this) to the onclick, etc.

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question, in the question it self, better still provide a [mcve]. Also don't provide images of code. They are **really** hard to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix. Scope your change to the parent of the element clicked.

Note there are better ways below

```js
$('.link-1').on('click', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest(".section");
    parent.find('.content-1').css({ 'display': 'block' });
    parent.find('.content-2').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    parent.find('.content-3').css({ 'display': 'none' });
});

$('.link-2').on('click', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest(".section");
    parent.find('.content-1').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    parent.find('.content-2').css({ 'display': 'block' });
    parent.find('.content-3').css({ 'display': 'none' });
});

$('.link-3').on('click', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest(".section");
    parent.find('.content-1').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    parent.find('.content-2').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    parent.find('.content-3').css({ 'display': 'block' });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.section-header {
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: none;
}

.content:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 117px;
}

.content:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 217px;
}

.link-colorchange {
  color: red;
}

.display {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Section 1</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-1">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-2">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-3">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content content-1">
        content 1
      </div>
      <div class="content content-2">
        content 2
      </div>
      <div class="content content-3">
        content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br />
  <br />

  <!-- Section 2 -->
  <div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Section 2</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-1">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-2">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-3">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content content-1">
        content 1
      </div>
      <div class="content content-2">
        content 2
      </div>
      <div class="content content-3">
        content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Better, it reduces duplicate code but isn't how I'd do it "in the real world". Note that the `display` rule is now more specific.

```js
$('.section a').on('click', function () {
    //Find the parent
    var parent = $(this).closest(".section");
    //Remove all display classes
    parent.find('.content').removeClass("display");
    //Add the class to our target.
    parent.find($("."+this.dataset.target)).addClass("display")
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.section-header {
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: none;
}

.content:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 117px;
}

.content:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 217px;
}

.link-colorchange {
  color: red;
}
/*Note this is now more specific*/
.content.display {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Section 1</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-1" data-target="content-1">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-2" data-target="content-2">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-3" data-target="content-3">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content content-1">
        content 1
      </div>
      <div class="content content-2">
        content 2
      </div>
      <div class="content content-3">
        content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br />
  <br />

  <!-- Section 2 -->
  <div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Section 2</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-1" data-target="content-1">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-2" data-target="content-2">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link link-3" data-target="content-3">link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content content-1">
        content 1
      </div>
      <div class="content content-2">
        content 2
      </div>
      <div class="content content-3">
        content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now if only there was a way to determine the target from a link without using a data attribute. Ooo look the `href` attribute. This will also make your page more semantic and possibly provide small SEO benefits.

```js
//Set even listener on section. Purely to demonstrate event delegation.
$(".section").on("click",function(e){
  //Check Link clicked
  if(e.target.matches("a")){
    //Remove display
    $(this).find(".content").removeClass("display");
    //Set display, based on href of element clicked
    $(e.target.getAttribute("href")).addClass("display");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.section-header {
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 20px;  
  display:none;
}


.content:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 117px;
}

.content:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 217px;
}

.link-colorchange {
  color: red;
}
/*Note this is now more specific*/
.content.display {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Section 1</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#S1C1" class="link link-1" >link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#S1C2" class="link link-2" >link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#S1C3" class="link link-3" >link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div id="S1C1" class="content content-1">
        content 1
      </div>
      <div id="S1C2" class="content content-2">
        content 2
      </div>
      <div id="S1C3" class="content content-3">
        content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br />
  <br />

  <!-- Section 2 -->
  <div class="section">
    <h2 class="section-header">Section 2</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#S2C1" class="link link-1" >link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#S2C2" class="link link-2" >link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#S2C3" class="link link-3" >link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div id="S2C1" class="content content-1">
        content 1
      </div>
      <div id="S2C2" class="content content-2">
        content 2
      </div>
      <div id="S2C3" class="content content-3">
        content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This approach would *almost* work without javascipt with CSS alone. What stops it from working is that in CSS you can only have one `:target` at a time, so you would only be able to display things in one section at a time.

Comment: Yes I see the multiple solutions, will look into them. Thanks so much for the help! Truly appreciate it!